# How can the Objective-C runtime know whether a weakly referenced object is still alive?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, objective-c-runtime

With the advent of ARC, some new functions were made available to allow developers to play around with weakly referenced objects. `id objc_loadWeak(id *location)` is one of them. This function receives one parameter correspoding to a location in memory where a weak object was stored and returns this object if it is still alive or `nil` if it were deallocated.

It seems that when an object `obj` is stored as `weak` in a location `location` with `id objc_storeWeak(id *location, id obj)`, `obj` is put in a "weak map", with `location` as a key. However, in order to retrieve `obj`, `objc_loadWeak` can not only use `location` as a key and return the value, which corresponds to `obj`. It must also check whether `obj` is still alive to return `nil` if it is not anymore.

However, `objc_loadWeak` can not try to read the object's retain count, because the object may have been deallocated. Moreover, although the weak map, `objc_storeWeak`, `objc_loadWeak` and the `NSObject` class are implemented in the same file ([NSObject.mm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm)), `NSObject`'s `dealloc` method doesn't signals to the weak map that the object that is being deallocated is going away.

So, how does the Objective-C runtime figure out whether a `weak` object is still alive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> NSObject's dealloc method doesn't signals to the weak map that the object that is being deallocated is going away.

It does.

```
- [NSObject dealloc]
```

calls

```
_objc_rootDealloc(self);
```

which in turn invokes

```
object_dispose()
```

which in turn calls

```
objc_destructInstance()
```

which finally calls

```
objc_clear_deallocating()
```

This last function looks like this:

```
    void 
objc_clear_deallocating(id obj) 
{
    assert(obj);
    assert(!UseGC);

    SideTable *table = SideTable::tableForPointer(obj); /* *** THIS LINE *** */

    // clear any weak table items
    // clear extra retain count and deallocating bit
    // (fixme warn or abort if extra retain count == 0 ?)
    OSSpinLockLock(&table->slock);
    if (seen_weak_refs) {
    arr_clear_deallocating(&table->weak_table, obj); /* *** THIS LINE *** */
    }
    table->refcnts.erase(DISGUISE(obj)); /* *** THIS LINE *** */
    OSSpinLockUnlock(&table->slock);
}
```

The three highlighted lines do the magic. `SideTable` is a C++ class implemented in `NSObject.mm` of which the `refcnts` member variable does exactly what it sounds like it does: it holds reference counts.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't follow the chain till the end. I stopped when I reached `object_dispose()`. Since this function is placed in another file, I thought it had nothing to do with weak references handling. Thank you very much!