# Is it safe to read a weak pointer while it's being deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, race-condition

Is it safe to read a nonatomic weak pointer from a different thread than the object is being deallocated from?

In general, I know properties should be made atomic whenever there may be simultaneous accesses, at least one of which is a write operation.  But I have to wonder if ARC's write operation (setting the pointer to nil) is somehow special.  Otherwise, I would've expected to see more warnings about this possible issue.  Perhaps weak pointers are implicitly atomic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe. Accessing weak pointer and Zeroing weak pointer is in between spinlock_lock and spinlock_unlock.

Take a look at the runtime source code
http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/NSObject.mm

Accessing weak pointer

```
id
objc_loadWeakRetained(id *location)
{
    id result;

    SideTable *table;
    spinlock_t *lock;

 retry:
    result = *location;
    if (!result) return nil;

    table = SideTable::tableForPointer(result);
    lock = &table->slock;

    spinlock_lock(lock);
    if (*location != result) {
        spinlock_unlock(lock);
        goto retry;
    }

    result = weak_read_no_lock(&table->weak_table, location);

    spinlock_unlock(lock);
    return result;
}
```

Zeroing weak pointer

```
void 
objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating()
{
    SideTable *table = SideTable::tableForPointer(this);

    // clear any weak table items
    // clear extra retain count and deallocating bit
    // (fixme warn or abort if extra retain count == 0 ?)
    spinlock_lock(&table->slock);
    RefcountMap::iterator it = table->refcnts.find(this);
    if (it != table->refcnts.end()) {
        if (it->second & SIDE_TABLE_WEAKLY_REFERENCED) {
            weak_clear_no_lock(&table->weak_table, (id)this);
        }
        table->refcnts.erase(it);
    }
    spinlock_unlock(&table->slock);
}
```

And the Object deallocating flow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14854977/629118